# Event Emitter @output on gridOptions.onRowDoubleClicked

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to recuperate a client from ag-grid on double-clicked a row.
I'm using angular 5 and ag-grid.

The ag-grid is as a child in a component called grid_client that I have injected in a Parent component called quotation-creation when I double click a given row I can console the clicked row in the child, but in the parent component, nothing appears! here is my code:
**Child: client-grid component**

```
@Output() clientRow  : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 createGridOptions() {
     this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
     this.gridOptions.onRowDoubleClicked = this.clientAdd;
    }
 clientAdd=(row)=>{
    this.clientRow.emit(row.data);
    console.log(row.data)// i could be sure that the row is displayed in the console
 }
```

**After that I called my event in the Parent:**

```
<h3>List of client</h3>
        <app-grid-client (clientRow)='rowClient($event) >//to display the grid and recuperate the event

    </app-grid-client>
```

in the ts of parent component

```
rowClient( row ) {
    console.log(row);
}
```

nothing appears in the parent component there is no error or undefined.

Could you please help to know why I didn't get the row clicked in the parent?

Comment: let me know if the answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an error in the HTML, you are missing the closing `'`, things seem to be tied up correctly in your JavaScript.

Please change this from:

```
<app-grid-client (clientRow)='rowClient($event) >//to display the grid and recuperate the event

</app-grid-client>
```

To

```
<app-grid-client (clientRow)='rowClient($event)' >//to display the grid and recuperate the event

</app-grid-client>
```

Comment: Hi Haris, thank you for your answer , yes it's a mistake when I copied the code sorry , but still having nothing. is there any ather way to recuparate a data from a parent to child?

Comment: do you see a row in the clientAdd() method?

Comment: yes I could display in the console the row that I doubleclicked,it's an object composed by all client information. I tryied to do somethning I just put the firstname in a new event :
 @Output() firstn  : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
then I emit only the firstname :
clientAdd=(row)=>{
    console.log(row.data);
    let firstName =row.data.firstName
    this.firstn.emit(firstName);
console.log(firstName);
 }
in the Parent I could recuperate the firstName of my object:
HTML:
<app-grid-client (firstn)='rowClient($event)'></app-grid-client>

Comment: okay, you can try and emit an object that you can create from your client information like so :
.emit({ Foo: true, FooBar: 1, SomeProperty: 100}) let me know if this helped I will update the answer or even .emit({Object: data})

Comment: Yess it works also! this.firstn.emit({firstName:row.data.firstName,address:row.data.address} )
Thanks very much for you kind help

Comment: And I think I found why with the variable clientRow did'nt work alos,
because somehow I initilized it again in my ngOninit:

ngOnInit() {
        this.clientRow  = new EventEmitter() ;
/// that caused an issue I guess
so I tryied again to emit the Object row and it's work fine now 
Thanks for your kind assistance Haris :)

Comment: glad to help, please mark the answer if it helped, it can help others too :)